# Notepad trick for backsapce

Tags: notepad++

If any line starts with comma(,) I want to append the complete line to previous line.

EX:My data in notepad++ is like :

```
one,hello,how,are 
,you
two,hello,I,am,fine
```

I want data like this:

```
one,hello,how,are,you
two,hello,I,am,fine
```

Is there any trick for this ?.

Comment: What programming language are you going to use to do this?

Comment: Well, this question is not about *general computing hardware and software*, NPP is widely used to help fix one's code.

Answer (score 2):

If the lines follow one another separated with `\r\n`, use *Extended Mode* and  use

Find what: `\r\n,`
Replace with: `,`

If the lines may have unknow type of linebreak, use a *Regular Expression* mode and use

Find What: `\R,`
Replace with: `,`

If there can be any amount of blank lines between the lines, add `+` after `\R` - `\R+,`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ has support for macros, plug-ins and regular expressions.  So I believe your options would be:
1. create a macro to do it.
2. find or create a plug-in to do it
3. Do a find and replace with regular expressions

Answer (score 1):

Use the search&replace dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>), enable the extended or regex mode, and replace the expression "`\n,`" by "`,`". Depending on your file, you might need "`\r\n,`". Then hit the button "Replace all".

Answer (score 1):

You want to press backspace at the beginning of every line that starts with a comma. In that case, you can search for a regular expression that matches a comma at the beginning (that is, `^,`), and then save a macro that presses F3 and then backspace.

To be more precise:

- Prepare the regular expression:

  - Open the search dialog (Ctrl-F)
  - Set Search mode to "Regular Expression"
  - Insert `^,`
  - Click at least once on "Find Next" (so that F3 will use that search), then close it
  - Verify that by pressing F3 it finds the beginning of a line that starts with a comma
- Now, prepare the macro:

  - Move the cursor to the top of the page
  - Click on Macro->Start recording
  - Press: F3, left-arrow, backspace
  - Click on Macro->Stop recording
- Run the Macro:

  - Click on Macro->Playback (or Ctrl-Shift-P) to run it. Do it as many times as needed. Alternatively, you can also select "Run macro multiple times" and specify "Run until the end of the file" to do it at one go.